# Bootstrap articles left a blank spot (SM size)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am developing a FE interface using **Bootstrap** and have a problem with boxes for **SM size**, instead of occupying the empty space and float to the left, the boxes leave a **blank spot** and make a line break...

Here a screenshot of the problem:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHJDF.png *

The HTML markup for that section (four articles in a row):

```
<!-- Articulo -->
  <article class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="" class="hidden-xs"><img src="http://placehold.it/730x300" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a></h2>
      <footer class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="listaInline">
          <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> xx/xx/xxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Editor</a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comentario</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
      <p>En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor. Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos y quebrantos los sábados, lantejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda. El resto della concluían sayo de velarte, calzas de velludo para las fiestas, con sus pantuflos de lo mesmo, y los días de entresemana se honraba con su vellorí de lo más fino.
      <a href="">Leer más <i class="fa fa-share"></i></a></p>
    </div>
  </article>
```

And the CSS for the articles:

```
/****************************************************************************************************
A R T I C U L O S
*****************************************************************************************************/
article {
    margin-top: 2.2em;
    padding: 0;
}

article:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

article > div {
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-right: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    border-left: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #fff;
}

article h2 a {
    color: #1d1d1b;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

article footer {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

article footer li {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

article footer li a {
    color: #c1c1c0;
}
```

Media query CSS:

```
    /****************************************************************************************************
A R T I C U L O S
*****************************************************************************************************/
article {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2.2em;
}

article > div {
    padding: 0;
}

article > #contenido {
    border-top: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
}

article h2 a {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Hope you can help me, greetings and thanks to all!

Comment: This is redundant <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">, since it's nested without a surrounding row, this is incorrect. Remove all column classes from that. The gaps are normal float behavior in CSS, investigate masonry layouts with jQuery. The footer is also not necessary to make col-lg-12, it will be 100% width by default. Also   <article class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> this is too much. Should be   <article class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look better bootstrap operation. A greeting.